# Variable form action="/"

Tags: django, django-forms

There is a web application that collects data from different sites. The form on the home page is presented in the form of two fields where you can choose from several variants of languages and cities. When you press the search button, the result is displayed only for one pair of languages and cities, regardless of the selected variant in the form, as there is only one url in the form action='''. How to make a dynamic change of form action='' depending on the choice of variant in the form on the main page. I hope I have explained it clearly. Thank you for any help!

https://ibb.co/VNcQqDp screenshot

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.language
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import PageForm
from page.parsers.kiev_python_parser import *
from page.parsers.kiev_javascript_parser import *
from page.parsers.kiev_java_parser import *
from page.parsers.kiev_c_parser import *


def index_page(request):
    form = PageForm()
    return render(request, 'page/index_page_form.html', context= 
{'form':form})


def kiev_python(request):
    kiev_python_main()
    return render(request, 'page/kiev_python_result.html', context= 
{'workua_data': workua_data, 'rabotaua_data':rabotaua_data})


def kiev_javascript(request):
    kiev_javascript_main()
    return render(request, 'page/kiev_javascript_result.html', 
 context={'workua_data': workua_data, 'rabotaua_data':rabotaua_data})


def kiev_java(request):
     kiev_java_main()
     return render(request, 'page/kiev_java_result.html', context= 
{'workua_data': workua_data, 'rabotaua_data':rabotaua_data})


 def kiev_c(request):
     kiev_c_main()
     return render(request, 'page/kiev_c_result.html', context= 
 {'workua_data': workua_data, 'rabotaua_data':rabotaua_data})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Page

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['language', 'city']

        lang_options = [
            ('1', 'Python'),
            ('2', 'Javascript'),
            ('3', 'Java'),
            ('4', 'C#'),
        ]


         city_options = [
              ('1', 'Киев'),
         ]

         language = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=lang_options)
          city = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=city_options)
```

index_page_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Main page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
     <h1 class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center">Сервис поиска работы</h1>
     <p class="text-center">Это веб приложение позволяет осуществить поиск вакансий для программистов с популярнейших ресурсов работодателей Украины</p>

<form action="/" method="post" class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="language-field">Выберите язык:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="language" id="language-field">
                <option name="kiev_python" value="1">Python</option>
                <option name="kiev_javascript" value="2">Javascript</option>
                <option name="kiev_java" value="3">Java</option>
                <option name="kiev_c" value="4">C#</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="city-field">Выберите город:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city-field">
                <option value="1">Киев</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block mt-3" type="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path

 from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    path('', index_page, name='index_page_url'),
    path('result/kiev_python/', kiev_python, name='kiev_python_url'),
    path('result/kiev_javascript/', kiev_javascript, name='kiev_javascript_url'),
    path('result/kiev_java/', kiev_java, name='kiev_java_url'),
    path('result/kiev_c_sharp/', kiev_c, name='kiev_c_url'),

]
```

Comment: You can use some JavaScript for that, but it is a bit odd to that in the first place, why not let the view itself do the proper routing?

Comment: What do you mean, proper routing? The question may seem silly, I recently started to study django and this is my first independent project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use django template so you can use a tag of the context which is dynamic. Something like this:

```
form action="/{{ your_path}}" method="post" class="mt-5 mb-5 text-center">
```

Comment: But there's only one url in there, like {"% 
url 'kiev_python_url' %} and it works for the whole form regardless of the option

Comment: There are two options. Either you POST your choices to a view and the view redirects you to your desired url or you use javascript on a a specific event i.e. onchange() of select `document.getElementById("your_form").action = "/your_url";`